# Возвращение JSX-разметки

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
convert = (item) => {
    let result;

    for (let value in item) {            
        result += <span>{item[value]}</span>
    }

    return result;
}

render() {
    return (            
        <div style={style}>         
            {
                this.convert(this.props.data)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Свойство `this.props.data` содержит объект. Необходимо все его свойства обернуть в тэг `span` и возвратить полученный результат. Но в итоге result возвращает: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте для этого лучше map.
`Object.keys(item).map(key => <span>item[key]</span>);`

Все же jsx это объекты, а не строки.
Важно в общем это все собрать в массив и вывести. Можете поступить так.

```
convert = (item) => {
    let result = [];

    for (let value in item) {            
        result.push(<span>{item[value]}</span>);
    }

    return result;
}

render() {
    return (            
        <div style={style}>         
            {
                this.convert(this.props.data)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Или так

```
convert = (item) => {
   return Object.keys(item).map(key => <span>item[key]</span>);
}

render() {
    return (            
        <div style={style}>         
            {
                this.convert(this.props.data)
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```